# Why does Jim Gray call "data-driven science" a new paradigm?

Tags: theory

Wikipedia it says about [data science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_science):

> Turing award winner Jim Gray imagined data science as a "fourth paradigm" of science (empirical, theoretical, computational and now data-driven) and asserted that "everything about science is changing because of the impact of information technology" and the data deluge.[4][5]

The term "theoretical" links to "basic research", which I believe to be false, since basic research can be also empirical. However, "theoretical" makes sense in contrast to empirical: In theoretical research you try to find solution "simply" by thinking about the problem, in empirical research you gather data on the problem, and use it to either build models/theories regarding reality or test these models/theories.

I do not see what computational science is supposed to be in *in contrast*, because I believe that I can use computer for both empirical science (e.g. using statistics and machine learning models) or in theoretical science (e.g. building simulations that are based on my assumptions and see if they result in the expected outcome - no data involved). So I think computational science would be a complement to empirical science and/or theoretical science, *not* a contrasting paradigm.

Now, comes in "data-driven science". How is this supposed to be different? Either you could say data-driven is just empirical (as I would say), so it is not a *new* paradigm. Or you might interpret it as "computational", then it is not even a paradigm.

Two lines of argumentation I came up with are invalid after all:

1. "While empirical science uses data, data-driven uses more data." But having more apples doesn't mean you didn't have apples before. This is quantitative, not qualitative. Paradigms are by definition qualitative different.
2. "We have different methods." We do have new machine learning methods, we did not have in statistics, but that does not change the general paradigm to collect data and use it to build models.

Questions:

- What does Jim Gray (allegedly) mean with "fourth paradigm"?
- Is he justified to call it a new paradigm akin to "empirical science" and "theoretical science"? (Please make an argument why!)

Comment: I wouldnt pay so much attention to it. It is just a view of a person plus the hype effect around buzzwords IMO. One can formulate another view on this and say for example that data are a return to empirical grounds. Whatever..

Comment: Paradigm and new Paradigm is used in the sense of [Kuhn's "Structure of Scientific Revolutions"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradigm_shift) which is a theory around revolutions in scientific thinking and methods which constitute a new paradigm (paradigm=a fixed and dominant set of ideas and associated methodology). However this paradigm shift has been claimed many times before for various areas which supposedly were so important that would make a paradigm shift (eg Non-linear systems and Chaos theory). Needless to say most of the times this is exaggerated and overly-hyped

Comment: @NikosM. Thanks! I have to say, with these seemingly un-substantiate / un-scientific opinions and definitions I get easily irritated at first, then I get insecure about my own irritation (afterall "even wikipedia believes this to be so") and whether I am just not getting it or missing something. Maybe my irritation is more often justified than my insecurity believes ;-). Not sure. The term data "science" itself in subject of some of my irritation.

Comment: Personally I am a big fan of Chaos Theory and Non-linear Dynamics and I would like it to be a paradigm shift. However the fact is that it rather enriched the dominant paradigm than radically changing it. Also increased interest in one area does not constitute a paradigm shift by itself. If enriching the paradigm can be considered a paradigm shift is debatable.